# SQL query to split one column into 2

Tags: sql

I have a table with name Numbers in that I have one column Integer. and I have positive as well as negative values in that column. I want to split the columns in such a way that in one column I get sum of positive integers and in second column I get sum of negative integers.

Comment: Can you provide some example data of Numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(case when int_col > 0 then int_col else 0 end) as pos,
       sum(case when int_col < 0 then int_col else 0 end) as neg
from numbers
```